# FontForge kerning Greek and Latin letters

Tags: font-forge, kerning

Is it actually possible to apply kerning between a greek letter, say delta, and a 'normal' letter, say 'A'? I can apply kerning between normal letters etc but can't manage to get a space between delta and 'A'.

I created a new lookup table and subtable and added a delta and 'A' and added a value for the kerning. I select the delta and open a new metrics window and have the delta and 'A' in there and the kerning does appear and seems to be working properly. But then when I actually generate the font and render it in the browser, no kerning shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been the topic of discussion on Typedrawers. Apparently shaping engines often break up text into sections of the same alphabet system and kern those sections, so it's not easy, although it may work in some cases.

https://typedrawers.com/discussion/comment/59018#Comment_59018
https://typedrawers.com/discussion/comment/24606

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. Thanks for your answer.